# is sending state of current component as a parameter to another external method possible in react

Tags: reactjs

```js
/** @jsx React.DOM */

// create a login component
var Login = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'loginComp',
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      id_uname: 'u',
      id_pwd: 'p'
    };
  },
  onChange: function(e){
    if(e.target.name=="username")
      this.setState({id_uname: e.target.value});
    else
      this.setState({id_pwd: e.target.value});
  },
  handleSubmit: function (e) {
    console.log(this.state.id_uname);
    console.log(this.state.id_pwd);
  },
  render: function () {
    var objState = this.state;
    var asd = "asd";

    return (
      <fieldset>
        <input ref='username' type="text" name="username" onChange={this.onChange}/>
        <input ref='password' type="password"  name="password" onChange={this.onChange}/>
        <button ref='password' type="submit" onClick={this.props.handleSubmit(this.state) ||  this.handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
      </fieldset>
    );
  }
});

var sub = function(state){
  console.log('-- OUTSIDE--');
  console.log('-- --',state);
};

React.renderComponent(
  <Login handleSubmit={sub}/>,
  document.body
);
```

When i click the button, it should go to sub method .. instead sub method responds to every state change and in the end when i press button it goes to default handleSubmit method .. Help !!

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
onClick={this.props.handleSubmit(this.state) ||  this.handleSubmit}
```

you're calling the `this.props.handleSubmit` handler immediately and setting its *result* as the onClick handler. I'm guessing you want to instead do a partial application, which you can do using `.bind`:

```
onClick={this.props.handleSubmit.bind(null, this.state)}
```

(Also, it's probably best to explicitly pass specific state keys to the handler, or else you may end up accidentally passing internal state on as you make future changes.)

Comment: Hi.. thanks for help .. by binding i get the state but it is initial state not the latest one .. after entering values.in my above example it just returns "u" and "p". How to i bind latest state.

Comment: @user3205633 Ben's fix worked for me. `this.state` is passed by reference, and so you will always get the correct values in `sub`. You can see it working in this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ssorallen/kQ48r/1/